# How do I prevent a view in my ListvView from being pushed out of view

Tags: android, listview

I list view with some text views in. one of the text views sometimes gets pushed out of view when  one of the other text view has a long string in it.

How do I make the text views ellipsize and never push other views out?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rest_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"

            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rest_rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1.5"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rest_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
         android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:capitalize="words"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rest_open"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Open"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's wierd, but if you take out

```
      android:capitalize="words"
```

you should see the results that you want. you don't even need `android:ellipsize="end"`

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rest_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:singleLine="true" // <-- the play maker
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: It doesnt work. it's not just rest_type its any textview but maintly rest_name

Comment: Maybe you can try using fixed values or match_parent for the boundaries